# How to Trim exactly 1 whitespace after splitting the string

Tags: c#, string, split, trim

I have made a program that evaluates a string by splitting it at a pipeline, the string are randomly generated and sometimes whitespace is a part of what need to be evaluated.

> HftiVfzRIDBeotsnU uabjvLPC | LstHCfuobtv eVzDUBPn jIRfai

This string is same length on either side(2 x whitespace on left side of pipeline), but my problem comes when i have to trim the space on both sides of the pipeline (i do this after splitting)
is there some way of making sure that i only trim 1 single space instead of them all.
my code  so far:

```
foreach (string s in str)
    {
        int bugCount = 0;
        string[] info = s.Split('|');
        string testCase = info[0].TrimEnd();
        char[] testArr = testCase.ToCharArray();
        string debugInfo = info[1].TrimStart();
        char[] debugArr = debugInfo.ToCharArray();
        int arrBound = debugArr.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrBound; i++)
            if (testArr[i] != debugArr[i])
                bugCount++;
        if (bugCount <= 2 && bugCount != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Low");
        if (bugCount <= 4 && bugCount != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Medium");
        if (bugCount <= 6 && bugCount != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("High");
        if (bugCount > 6)
            Console.WriteLine("Critical");
        else 
            Console.WriteLine("Done");

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: If you want to clear spaces before and after the pipe symbol then use `TrimStart` and `TrimEnd` http://www.dotnetperls.com/trimend

Comment: assuming you split on `|`, just take a substring of your string from [1] to [len-1] ?

Comment: Can you show produced by code and wanted result? I don't understand how `TrimEnd` or `TrimStart` can cause a problem here.

Comment: @sharpstudent wont work if theres a space as part of the string

Comment: @Sinatr I expect its when a space is at the end of the actual data in section 1 or the start of the actual data in section 2

Comment: no my smaple string doesnt, because i didnt know how to format it in the question. thats why i wrote that i has 2..

Comment: @Claudi: just use the editor's code button after you've selected the string you want to format as code. In the same way you've used it or your real code.

Comment: @Jamiec, oh that. Then answer is obvious: do not use `TrimX`, use e.g. `String.Substring` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You  have 2 options.

1. If there is *always* 1 space before and after the pipe, split on `{space}|{space}`.

   ```
   myInput.Split(new[]{" | "},StringSplitOptions.None);
   ```
2. Otherwise, instead of using `TrimStart()` & `TrimEnd()` use `SubString`.

   ```
   var split = myInput.Split('|');
   var s1 = split[0].EndsWith(" ") 
                    ? split[0].SubString(0,split[0].Length-1) 
                    : split[0];
   var s2 = split[1].StartsWith(" ")
                    ? split[1].SubString(1) // to end of line
                    : split[1];
   ```

Note, there is some complexity here - if the pipe has no space around it, but the last/first character is a legitimate (data) space character the above will cut it off. You need more logic, but hopefully this will get you started!

Comment: it seems im misunderstading something, when i try to use method 1, i get "cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'char'

Comment: @Claudi - see update, I forgot for that  [overload of `string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) you need to pass`StringSplitOptions`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell the `Trim..` methods family to stop after cutting out some number of characters.

In general case, you'd need to do it manually by inspecting the parts obtained after `Split` and checking their first/last characters and substring'ing to get the correct part.

However, in your case, there's a much simpler way - the Split can also take a `string` as an argument, and even more - a set of strings:

```
string[] info = s.Split(new []{ " | " });
// or even
string[] info = s.Split(new []{ " | ", " |", "| ", "|" });
```

That should take care of the single spaces around the pipe `|` character by simply treating them as a part of the separator.

Comment: yes, i agree. i only thought i could split on a char, this helps my in so many ways.

Answer (score 0):

This is a string extension to trim space for count times, just in case.

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Trim space at the end of string for count times
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="count">number of space at the end to trim</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string TrimEnd(this string input, int count = 1)
    {
        string result = input;
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (result.EndsWith(new string(' ', count)))
        {
            result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - count);
        }
        return result;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Trim space at the start of string for count times
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="count">number of space at the start to trim</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string TrimStart(this string input, int count = 1)
    {
        string result = input;
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        if (result.StartsWith(new string(' ', count)))
        {
            result = result.Substring(count);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the main

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string a = "1234  ";
   string a1 = a.TrimEnd(1); // returns "1234 "
   string a2 = a.TrimEnd(2); // returns "1234"
   string a3 = a.TrimEnd(3); // returns "1234  "

   string b = "  5678";
   string b1 = b.TrimStart(1); // returns " 5678"
   string b2 = b.TrimStart(2); // returns "5678"
   string b3 = b.TrimStart(3); // returns "  5678"
}
```